# Extract first n characters from original string while modifying original string -- effectively str_splice()

Tags: php, string, trim, substr, array-splice

Say we have string like:

```
$string = 'ADJKANKNAKLNKALNFKLANFKLNAKLFNKALN';
```

Say we need to declare a variable containing the first 5 characters (`ADJKA`) from `$string` and remove the first 5 characters from original string.

```
$first = 'ADJKA';
$string = 'NKNAKLNKALNFKLANFKLNAKLFNKALN';
```

Is there any function in PHP which can achieve this without using second function?  I am thinking something similar to the behavior of `array_splice()`, but with an input string instead of an input array.

(I know that `str_splice()` isn't a native php function.)

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
$string = substr_replace($string, '', 0, 5);
```

I was bored:

```
list($five, $string) = preg_split('/(^.{5})/', $string, null,
                                  PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In [non-buggy versions of php](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80866), you can "catch-n-release" the first five characters with `\K` and limit the splits to a 2-element maximum.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uQKiF))

```
$string = 'ADJKANKNAKLNKALNFKLANFKLNAKLFNKALN';

[$first5, $string] = preg_split('~.{5}\K~', $string, 2);

var_export([$first5, $string]);
```

Or you can avoid the `\K` bugs and use a lookbehind.

```
preg_split('~(?<=.{5})~', $string, 2)
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'ADJKA',
  1 => 'NKNAKLNKALNFKLANFKLNAKLFNKALN',
)
```